Adapt plotweb (bipartite) to plot multiple comparable networks
I have four networks (plant-pollinator-data of four site-types) I would like to show next to each other.
Can anyone recommend a way how to plot & export several different bipartite networks (with plotweb)  so that they have (if not exact at least approximately) the same boxwidth and same distance between the boxes?
Ideally the boxwidth should be in relation to the ammount of pollinators/plants, so that an interaction with one pollinator has the same thickness in all four networks to make visual comparison between the networks easier.
Another note concerning my networks: the ammount of interactions is very different with the smallest network having only 22 and the biggest having >150 interactions.
For example purposes two networks with different ammount of species and numbers:
network1 <- matrix(c(30, 1, 23, 3, 8, 5), nrow = 2)
network2<- matrix(c(5, 7, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2,1, 1,1,2), nrow = 4)
# code for producing the graphs: 
pdf(file="Network1.pdf",width= 30, height = 10)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
plotweb(network1, method = "normal", col.interaction = "grey", text.low.col = "black", labsize = 4, text.rot = 90)
dev.off()
#the widht and height would be different for the example data


I already tried changing the parameter width in pdf(), but it did not work that well: width changed the general width of the plot with either the distance or the thickness of the boxes or both in a way that seemed more random. E.g. I tried to plot the width in relation to the ammount of interaction.
In general I found not that many information on how to customize a plotweb except for this https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-do-I-customize-a-plotweb-graph-in-bipartite-package
Unfortunately here the parameters are not explained well. I tried using high.spacing and low.spacing, but the height of the plot shrank down a lot as well.
So before just accepting the differences in the plots I wanted to ask whether someone has got an idea?
Thank you very much in advance!
